# How to include a variable in a laravel redirect

Tags: laravel, redirect, laravel-5

I have a variable in a Laravel 5 controller which I am trying to include in the url of a redirect link, however nothing I've tried seems to work, my code is currently as follows.

```
$newChallenge = ((int) request('challenge_id') + 2);

return redirect('/texttext/{{$newChallenge}}');
```

However, this doesn't use the variable represented by $newChallenge, but rather
     "{{newChallenge}}" as a string, how should this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{ }}` is meant for use in blade files.

I think you can do `return redirect('/texttext/{ $newChallenge }');` if you really want those { } brackets.

Or just `return redirect(sprintf('/texttext/%s'), $newChallenge));`

or `return redirect('/texttext/'.$newChallenge);`

Edit: Also, your redirect could probably benefit from being a named route. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes

Answer (score 0):

May be you can change it to a query parameter

like

```
return redirect('/texttext/?=newChallenge={{$newChallenge}}');
```

if you want to use

```
return redirect('/texttext/{{$newChallenge}}');
```

It should be something like below

```
Route::get('texttext/{{newChallenge}}', 'YourController@newChallenge');
```

and newChallenge signature will `function newChallenge(Request $request, $newChallenge)`

if you want to use something like `return redirect(route('new-challenge', $newChallenge));`

just add name to route like

```
Route::get('texttext/{{newChallenge}}', 'YourController@newChallenge')->name('new-challenge');
```

I have not tested, but I think it should work.